# How do i render an object of multiple components in Storybook 7.0?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

I have an object that is called Text containing styled components, like this:

```js
export const Text = {   Heading1,   Heading2,   Heading3,   Heading4,   Heading5, }
```

I want do render them in a list on the same page on storybook. I cant seem to find the solution for this. Storybook 7 is very new and I don't want to use deprecated solutions.

My attempt:

```js
import type { Meta, StoryObj } from '@storybook/react'import { CustomText } from './Typography'

const meta: Meta<typeof CustomText> = {title: 'Typography',component: CustomText,}

export default meta

type Story = StoryObj<typeof CustomText>

export const Template: Story = {render: (args) => {return (<>{Object.entries(Text).map(([key, Component]) => {return (<Component key={key} {...args}>{key}</Component>)})}</>)},}
```

Storybook shows a blank page, any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make sure your story is a jsx or tsx (if you're using typescript) file.

You can then do the following (or variations thereof) this is how I did it recently.

```
const components = Array(12)
  .fill(null)
  .map((_, index) => <Component key={index} {...componentData} />);

export const Primary: Story = {
  args: {
    children: components
  }
};
```

The `...componentData` spread operator assumes that componentData contains the necessary props for the  component. If componentData is an object that needs to be spread into the  component, this code is fine. However, if you need to pass different data to each card, you'll need to adjust the code accordingly.